# How to resolve subquery by using join condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a emp table columns as deptno,ename and i have dept table columns as deptno,dname.  In emp table

```
Deptno   ename              
10       pavan
20       rav
30       kah
40       pab
```

IN DEPT TABLE

```
deptno   dname
10       sales
20       marketing
30       research
40       sales
```

Q) Find  ename of any employee in the same department name as pavan. How to write subquery by using join condition?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select ename from 
emp e
where e.Deptno = 
(select deptno from emp 
where ename='pavan')
```

**SQL Fiddle demo**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/867b3/12

Comment: Can i write like this; select e.deptno,e.ename from emp_table e,dept_table d where e.deptno=d.deptno and dname=(select dname from dept_table d,emp_table e where e.deptno=d.deptno and ename='pavan').

Comment: @user5618269 why do you want to join `dept` table anyways. It is not needed for your output. This answer will give you want you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to use `JOIN` instead of `Sub-query`. I guess, the question is to use a `JOIN` without using a `Sub-query.`

Please execute the below query:

```
SELECT
    E1.Deptno,
    E2.ename 
FROM Employees E1
    INNER JOIN Employees E2 ON E2.Deptno = E1.Deptno
WHERE
    E1.ename='pavan'
```